# How to secure Chatbot's API with Azure AD

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, botframework

My chatbot with Microsofts Bot Framework is online and working. It has an API, which is sadly publicly accessible.
But it shouldnt! The API should be secured and only accessible for Microsoft Accounts of my Tenant.

But most of the time the API is accessed by scripts.

Whats the best way to secure?
What is comfortable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other public APIs, your API (your bot) needs to implement some form of user auth in order to validate authorized requests and reject unauthorized requests. Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) (the C# version is linked, but the repo has samples in other languages) to see how you can implement user auth using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api). In addition to auth, Graph will also allow you to get info about the user, such as their Tenant ID (assuming your user logs-in and grants your bot permission). You can then implement whatever access controls are appropriate for your scenario.